# How do I launch WebSphere Portal Admin Console

Tags: websphere-portal

I have WebSphere Portal 8.0 on my laptop running Windows 7 Professional and I do not know how to launch the admin console.

I tried typing at the command prompt install-directory\wp-profile\bin startServer server1
and get a FileNotFoundException.  When I look into the log it says...

Exception java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\IBM\WebSphere\wp_profile\config\cells\Mitch-PCCell\nodes\Mitch-PCNode\servers\server1\server.xml (The system cannot find the path specified.)

inside the "server" folder in above error is another folder for WebSphere_Portal but not for server1.

Many thanks in advance.

PS:  I am very very very new to WebSphere Portal :)

Answer (score 1):

Start the WebSphere_Portal server instead of server1. The WebSphere_Portal server is where Portal is actually installed. I don't think server1 is really used for anything any more in Portal 8.

Answer (score 1):

10032 for https!!

Url is https://localhost:10032/ibm/console

and that's it

Answer (score 0):

1. Open a terminal.
2. Go to C:\IBM\WebSphere\wp_profile\bin.
3. Start Server with this: startServer WebSphere_Portal.

> ```
> Default Admin Console Url is : localhost:10032/ibm/console
> ```

Answer (score 0):

To find out the console port
from the IBM/Websphere folder
find and open AboutThisProfile.txt

Look for these values:

Administrative console port: 9102
Administrative console secure port: 9104

Then depending weather it is secure or not, use the following:
https://localhost:9104/ibm/console

http://localhost:9102/ibm/console

Answer (score 0):

All the ports can be checked in Ports Page (WAS9 is referred here ).

**Application Servers -> (Choose your server) -> Ports**

Port of **wc_adminhosts** will be for admin console

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on Rational Application Developer IDE and looking for admin console follow below

- Look for the Server Palette usually bottom pane in IDE and see if you have the server configured as shown below [image]
- find the mouse over Administration , then click on Run Administration console tab
- this will open the admin console in IDE's internal browser